# Upload Image using Android force closed but still working

Tags: android, mysql, image-uploading

Basically I can successfully add the photo but it just show force close dialog instead of toasting the successful message. Or if the image is too big, it will show "virtual memory overload......." I need to know whats the problem that makes it force closed. Leaked Window?

```
public class Admin_EditRestaurantImage extends Activity{

// declare TAG and URL for interaction with PHP JSON purpose
private static final String TAG_RID = "rid"; 
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String uploadImageURL = "http://192.168.224.1/FYP/admin_updateRestaurantImage.php";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//constructor
ListValuePairs lvp = new ListValuePairs();
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//variables
EditText name;
String rid, uripath, image, imgname;
Uri currImageURI;
Intent getI;
int success;
Vibrator vibrator;

//declare main
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_updateimage);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    //get intent and the value from previous layout
    getI = getIntent();
    rid = getI.getStringExtra(TAG_RID);


    //initialized gallerybtn
    Button gallerybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gallerybtn_updateimage);
    gallerybtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            //set vibrate for 0.5 seconds whenever the button is clicked
            vibrator.vibrate(50);

            //to open up a gallery browser
            Intent imageI = new Intent();
            imageI.setType("image/*");
            imageI.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(imageI,"Select Picture.."),1);          

        }

    });

    //initialized uploadbtn
    Button uploadbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadbtn_updateimage);
    uploadbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            //set vibrate for 0.5 seconds whenever the button is clicked
            vibrator.vibrate(50);

            // assign to XML layout and retrieve value into variables
            name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_updateimage);
            imgname = name.getText().toString();

            //check if the fields is empty or not
            if (imgname.trim().length() <1){

                //if yes, toast error message to user
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please name your picture..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{

                image = imgname + ".jpg";

                //execute httpuploader class
                new HttpUploader().execute(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));       
            }
        }

    });

} // end of main

// To handle when an image is selected from the browser
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {

            // currImageURI is the global variable to hold the content
            currImageURI = data.getData();
            uripath = getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);

            // check log cat from response
            Log.e("upload image path contains = " , uripath);

            // assign to XML layout and set value into the view
            TextView path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path_updateimage);
            path.setText(getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI));
            ImageView image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_updateimage);
            image_view.setImageURI(currImageURI);

        }

    }
}

//Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI( Uri contentUri) {
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
            proj,     // columns to return
            null,     // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
            null,     // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null);     // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String c = cursor.getString(column_index); 
    return c;
}

//======================================================================
//create async class for HttpUploader 
public class HttpUploader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    //show dialog to user what is going on
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Admin_EditRestaurantImage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image... Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    //create background thread
    protected String doInBackground(String... path) {

        try{
            for (String sdPath : path) {
                Log.e("path got what",sdPath);
                Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdPath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                //Resize the image
                double width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
                double height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
                double ratio = 400/width;
                int newheight = (int)(ratio*height);

                bitmapOrg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, 400, newheight, true);

                //Here you can define .PNG as well
                bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bao);
                byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                //call editRestaurantImage function from ListValuePair to converted them into value pairs data then pass value through json
                List<NameValuePair> params_uploadImg = lvp.editRestaurantImage(rid, ba1, image);
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(uploadImageURL, "POST", params_uploadImg);

                //track the values in the json by using Log
                Log.e("image json contains = ", json.toString());

                //clear the memory of image allocation previously
                //bitmapOrg.recycle();

                // check for success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                //if the success is equals to 1
                if(success == 1){

                    //toast successful message to user
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    //toast error message to user
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




            } // end of for loop
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    //create ending process 
    protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

        // dismiss the dialog once got all details  
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
} // end of HttpUploader class

} // end of class
```

logcat shows things that i could'not find. I check the lines shows there line 208, 1 , 165, 108, they dont have problems at all. what does it mean by leaked window?

```
05-17 18:43:46.319: E/upload image path contains =(4980): /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0133.jpg
05-17 18:43:46.369: D/dalvikvm(4980): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 666K, 47% free 3525K/6535K, external 1178K/1690K, paused 29ms
05-17 18:43:47.681: D/View(4980): onTouchEvent: viewFlags: 0x18004001
05-17 18:43:47.681: D/View(4980): onTouchEvent: isFocusable: true, isFocusableInTouchMode: false, isFocused: false; focusTaken: false
05-17 18:43:47.701: D/WindowManagerImpl(4980): addView, new view, mViews[2]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40518d30
05-17 18:43:47.721: E/path got what(4980): /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0133.jpg
05-17 18:43:47.781: D/dalvikvm(4980): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 88K, 47% free 3486K/6535K, external 16892K/18940K, paused 40ms
05-17 18:43:48.572: I/dalvikvm-heap(4980): Clamp target GC heap from 32.611MB to 32.000MB
05-17 18:43:48.572: D/dalvikvm(4980): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 221K, 44% free 3779K/6663K, external 25271K/26797K, paused 27ms
05-17 18:43:48.832: E/image json contains =(4980): {"message":"Image Successfully Updated!","success":1}
05-17 18:43:48.832: W/dalvikvm(4980): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage$HttpUploader.doInBackground(Admin_EditRestaurantImage.java:208)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage$HttpUploader.doInBackground(Admin_EditRestaurantImage.java:1)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
05-17 18:43:48.842: E/AndroidRuntime(4980):     ... 4 more
05-17 18:43:49.192: D/WindowManagerImpl(4980): finishRemoveViewLocked, mViews[1]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405aa558
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980): Activity com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40518d30 that was originally added here
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40518d30 that was originally added here
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:278)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage$HttpUploader.onPreExecute(Admin_EditRestaurantImage.java:165)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at com.example.pras.Admin_EditRestaurantImage$2.onClick(Admin_EditRestaurantImage.java:108)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2533)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
```

05-17 18:43:49.202: E/WindowManager(4980):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I am a beginner in this, anyone could let me know whats that error mean please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

You are getting below exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
>       called Looper.prepare()

Just because of below code:

```
//if the success is equals to 1
if(success == 1){

      //toast successful message to user
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }else{
      //toast error message to user
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

### Why are you getting this exception?

You are trying to display Toast message from the doInBackground() method, that is from the non-UI thread.

### Solution:

Whenever you want to display/update UI while doing long-running process using `AsyncTask`, you can implement either of the below solution:

1. Update UI inside `onPostExecute()` method. // Standard way
2. Implement `runOnUiThread()` and update UI inside `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 2):

As in Log:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

because you are trying to show `Toast` Messages from `doInBackground` method means from non-ui Thread . to avoid this error you will need to return `success` from `doInBackground` to `onPostExecute` which always run on UI Thread.

```
//create ending process 
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {

    // dismiss the dialog once got all details  
    pDialog.dismiss();
    //show Toast message here....
}
```